# What is logical key hierarchy (LKH)?

Tags: keys

The question [*"Virtual key generation in Logical Key Hierarchy"*](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/48038/virtual-key-generation-in-logical-key-hierarchy) asks how specific keys are constructed in LKH. Since I haven't heard of it and it isn't immediately obvious (not even from the linked [RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-harney-sparta-lkhp-sec-00)) what it does or how, can somebody provide a short explanation?

Answer (score 3):

> Since I haven't heard of it and it isn't immediately obvious (not even from the linked RFC) what it does or how, can somebody provide a short explanation?

In short, Logical Key Hierarchy – LKH – is a solution to handle keying issue in secure group communication. LKH is interesting because it allows keying in an efficient and scalable way by minimizing the number of transmissions in rekeying as well as storage requirements. (At it's core, there's a binary tree.)

You might want to check the ample materials available online (which you can find using your favorite search engine) for examples. Mentioning only two random materials of many: there's [a short, 15 page lecture from 2003 by D.R. Stinson](http://cgi.di.uoa.gr/~halatsis/Crypto/Bibliografia/Crypto_Lectures/Stinson_lectures/lec20.pdf) (PDF) and there's [Logical Key Hierarchy Protocol](https://discovery.csc.ncsu.edu/Courses/csc774-S03/Presentations/02-LKH.pdf) (PDF) for a protocol example.